# Passing nonce at admin menu link

Tags: plugin-development, nonce

I'm trying to pass a nonce at the links created from my plugin using `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`.
Of course this is invalid:

```
add_submenu_page(
 'my_dashboard',
 'Dashboard',
 'Dashboard',
 'manage_options',
 'my_dashboard&nonce-field=' . wp_create_nonce('my_action'),
 'show_dashboard'
);
```

as per the Codex, the slug should [only include lowercase alphanumeric, dashes, and underscores characters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/).

So my question is, how could we pass nonce in the URL of the menu links a plugin creates?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Not clear on why you need a nonce here. There's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm trying to verify nonce (either with `check_admin_referer()` or with `wp_verify_nonce()`, at the body of the `show_dashboard` function, but to do that, I must pass a nonce field at the initial URL.

Comment: I use a `$_GET` variable inside the `show_dashboard` function, so if I don't have nonce verification, it would produce an error of the WordPress Code Standards.

Comment: When are you using `$_GET`? After submitting a form? In that case you're supposed to use a nonce field in the form so that it gets added to the URL when you submit.

Comment: I'm not submitting a form unfortunately. I'm just checking for `$_GET` parameters inside the function to be called to output the content for this page, because this specific page is used for many stages at the plugin, so I have to check the `$_GET` parameters to check at what stage I'm currently at.

Comment: Why not put the nonce in the links to each stage, rather than on the main link?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress do not accept nonce in the slug that you are trying to provide in the above code.

I mean in this line:

```
 'my_dashboard&nonce-field=' . wp_create_nonce('my_action'), 'show_dashboard'
```

I was facing the same issue like you are facing. As the admin menu already verified for specific users so we don't need to verify it again with nonce. Therefore, to skip that issue you can use that code at top of your file where you using $_GET or $_POST super global.

```
check_admin_referer(-1);
```

It will remove the warning for nonce verification.

Comment: As of version 3.2 it throws a notice type of error if you don't provide the first (action) argument. But it does help to bypass the codesniffer warning.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is 3.2 version?

Comment: * As of WordPress version 3.2

Comment: I don't know but why you are using very old version of WordPress. It has so many security issues.  So I think you should update WordPress version to latest.

Comment: In the above Saroar Hossain answer. There is still an error i.e. "Notice: Function check_admin_referer was called incorrectly. You should specify an action to be verified by using the first parameter." How to resolve this as I have an already updated verion of Wordpress i.e. 6.2.